# Errors 'Root project path of the Gradle project not found for Module: 'Pegboard'' and 'Failed to notify project evaluation listener'

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

Normally I use a `Mac` to develop but today I installed `Android Studio` for `Windows` and downloaded a project I'm working on.  `Gradle` fails with the error `Failed to notify project evaluation listener.`

In addition, `Android Studio` gave an error `Root project path of the Gradle project not found for Module: 'Pegboard'`.

The `Gradle` error details:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Pegboard'.
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
...
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
...
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.SubpluginEnvironment.addSubpluginOptions(KotlinPlugin.kt:702)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor$doTargetSpecificProcessing$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:158)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor$doTargetSpecificProcessing$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:128)
...
```